# What happens in a conductor when the electric field has a plasma frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, conductors

The complex index of refraction for a conductor is given  by the equation: $$N(\omega)=n+ik=\sqrt{1- \frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2+i\gamma\omega}} $$ where $\omega_p^2=Nq_e/\epsilon_0m_e$ is the plasma frequency, $\omega$ is the frequency of the electric field inside the conductor, and $\gamma$ is the damping constant of the material. For $\omega≅\omega_p≅10^{16}Hz>>\gamma≅10^{14}Hz$ we find that:$$N(\omega)=n+ik≅0$$ hence in the near UV $n≅0$ and $k≅0$. What does this physically mean ?

Comment: The metal becomes transparent. [Feynman - Section 32.6 Waves in a metal](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_32.html)

Comment: Thank you very much !